# Correctly exporting global.d.ts into an npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I want to publish a typescript npm package, with types embedded.
My folder structure is as follows

```
dist/
   [...see below]
src/
   global.d.ts
   index.ts 
   otherfile.ts
test/
examples/
```

For the sake of an example, my global.d.ts file includes typings relevant to the whole project.
My index.d.ts file uses these types, and exports functions.

```
//global.d.ts
interface Dog {
 name: string,
 age: number
}
//more types...
```

```
//index.ts
import {func1, func2} from './otherfile.ts'
export default function getDogName(dog: Dog): string {
  return dog.name
}
export {func1, func2}
```

I can build this code, and it all runs correctly, so typescript knows about `global.d.ts`. Yet, when I run tsc (using the below config), it generates files into my `dist/` folder, which *doesnt* include the `global.d.ts` file. ie: dist only contains `index.d.ts` and `otherfile.d.ts`. Shouldn't `dist/` also contain `global.d.ts`? If not - how will people who install my package know the types for Dog?

My config looks like this for build time.

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "declaration": true
  },
  // Only point to typings and the start of your source, e.g. `src/index.ts`
  "include": [ "src/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "examples", "test"]
 }
```

For reference, the actual repo is here: https://github.com/bhaviksingh/lsystem

Comment: "global" types is a code smell. Just import it

Answer (score 5):

Alright :) After much experimentation, I wanted to share what I did.
There are potentially better solutions (would love to find them), but the TLDR is that I changed it from a global declaration file, to a regular TS module, and exported/imported all the types.

So I renamed the `global.d.ts` file, to just be `interfaces.ts`, and then exported the type.

```
//interfaces.ts (renamed from global.d.ts)
export interface Dog {
 name: string,
 age: number
}
//more types...
```

I imported this type into index.d.ts and re-exported it

```
//index.ts
import Dog from "./interfaces"
export {Dog}
```

TSConfig knows to compile these declarations

```
//tsconfig.global.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "declaration": true
  },
  // Only point to typings and the start of your source, e.g. `src/index.ts`
  "include": [ "src/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "examples/", "test/"]
 }
```

and my package.json points to the compiled declaration file.

```
//package.json
{
 //...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    //...
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.global.json",
  },
}
```

There are probably better solutions out there, potentially including `/// <reference path="..." />`  tags, but this is what I have for now and it works. When people install my library, they have access to the types in intellisense, and if they want to use the types they can be imported.

Comment: Kind of annoying that `tsc` can't just add the `import` statements automatically for global types, but oh well. Thanks for sharing your solution!